# Pivot table "does not contain" when you have more than one variable

Tags: excel, vba

I basically want to include two things that the pivot table does not contain.  In the code below it has Chev and Mac.

Am happy to do this in Excel or in VBA.

```
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Traders Name"). _
      ClearLabelFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Traders Name").PivotFilters _
    .Add Type:=xlCaptionDoesNotContain, Value1:="mac"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Traders Name").PivotFilters _
    .Add Type:=xlCaptionDoesNotContain, Value1:="chev"
```

I know I could add an extra column in my original data source which would take out the ones with info I don't need and then use that as a filter.  However, I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: You can't do it directly with a filter, but you could do it in VBA by simply looping through the pivotitems, testing each using `Instr` to make sure it doesn't contain either value, then setting the `.Visible` property accordingly.

Comment: I have also got a top ten filter on the pivot would that still work?  As in show me the top ten.

Comment: On the same field? Do you want the mac and chev data included if it would be in the top 10?

Comment: They are the same field. I don't want them included if they are in the top ten.  Am thinking of taking them out then putting the top ten filter on after.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help somebody with the same issue:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Traders Name")
.PivotItems("mac").Visible = False
.PivotItems("chev").Visible = False
```